# Splitting a column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to split a dataframe in pyspark
This is the data i have

```
df = sc.parallelize([[1, 'Foo|10'], [2, 'Bar|11'], [3,'Car|12']]).toDF(['Key', 'Value'])
df = df.withColumn('Splitted', split(df['Value'], '|')[0])
```

I got

```
+-----+---------+-----+
|Key|Value|Splitted   |
+-----+---------+-----+
|    1|   Food|10|   F|
|    2|   Bar|11 |   B|
|    3|   Caring 12| C|
+-----+---------+-----+
```

But i want

```
+-----+---------+-----+
|Key  | Value|Splitted|
+-----+---------+-----+
|    1|   10|  Food   |
|    2|   11|  Bar    |
|    3|   12|Caring   |
+-----+---------+-----+
```

Can any one please point me to what i am doing wrong?

```
What if i have a unique situation like this?
df = sc.parallelize([[1, 'Foo|10|we'], [2, 'Bar|11|we'], [3,'Car|12|we']]).toDF(['Key', 'Value'])

+---+---------+
|Key|    Value|
+---+---------+
|  1|Foo|10|we|
|  2|Bar|11|we|
|  3|Car|12|we|
+---+---------+
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot the `escape` character, you should include escape character as

```
df = df.withColumn('Splitted', split(df['Value'], '\|')[0])
```

If you want output as

```
+---+-----+--------+
|Key|Value|Splitted|
+---+-----+--------+
|1  |10   |Foo     |
|2  |11   |Bar     |
|3  |12   |Car     |
+---+-----+--------+
```

You should do

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('Splitted', F.split(df['Value'], '\|')).withColumn('Value', F.col('Splitted')[1]).withColumn('Splitted', F.col('Splitted')[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, is there any reason why the eventype column still contains "Food"?

Comment: i updated my question, can you please take a look at it? Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the updated dataframe? You can find enough answers for that I guess. So research on that if you dont find an answer ask another question i and orhers would certainly help you :)

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured it out as soon as i posted the questing.

Comment: Why does an escape character needed? In a case I had, the delimiter was a dot ('.') and only when adding the escape character ('\.') it did the correct split